# Overwrite background image (using background package) by PDF (using pdfpages package)

Tags: pdfpages, backgrounds

I just want to see the PDF clearly. Is there a way to overwrite the background image (jpg file) by the PDF using pdfpages package? Or is there a way to use opacity for the PDF separately?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11.7in, paperheight=8.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\backgroundsetup{
position={5.4125in,-3.5in},
scale=.9,
angle=-.5,
opacity=0.2, 
contents={\includegraphics{ImageName}}
}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{filename}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the exact output you require. Here, first pdf content is loaded then the image with the defined opacity. What else is required?

Comment: I want to put the PDF file over (above) the background. It seems that the background opacity changes the visibility of the PDF. Again, PDF included with the pdfpages package produces the PDF file as a background. I want the file in PDF format displayed over the background image clearly.

Comment: It may be noted that the PDF file to be included contains only the words typed in LaTex only.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. Please add further queries to the comments so that I can enhance it as per the requirement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=11.7in, paperheight=8.3in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=0.9,
opacity=0.2,
angle=-.5,
position={5.4125in,-3.5in},
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Small-mario.png}
  }%
}
\begin{document}
 \BgThispage
 \includepdf[pages=-]{Test2}
 \clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that as the opacity of the background increases, the visibility of the text (imported by pdfpages) decreases. I want to avoid it.

Comment: What is the value of opacity you are using

Comment: When opacity becomes bigger like 0.5, the visibility of the text decreases.

Comment: When the opacity of the background is 0.9, the text of the imported PDF becomes almost invisible. Isn't it? It seems that the opacity of the background affects the imported PDF.

Comment: Yes it is observed. Unfortunately, I don't see any option to change opacity of pdf content.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `background` package is build on `tikz` and `pdfpages` is built on `graphicx`, specifically the `\includegraphics` command, you could just do this.

In a `tikzpicture` environment, put the image on a background layer using the `pgfonlayer` environment. The pdf can be laid over the background image by placing it on the main layer, which does not have to be explicit written in the code. You can set the opacity of the background images to whatever you want without affecting the visibility of the pdf laid over the top. This is illustrated for three background images with `opacity=0.9`, `opacity=0.5` and `opacity=0.1`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MWE} % for example-image-a.png and example-image-a4.pdf
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} % for (current page text area.north)
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % for {pgfonlayer}{background}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}   % add the background layer
\pgfsetlayers{background,main} % specify the order of the layers

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
% Put images in the background
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[opacity=0.9,anchor=north] (A) at (current page text area.north) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
\node[opacity=0.5,below=3cm]  (B)   at (A.south) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
\node[opacity=0.1,below=3cm]  (C)   at (B.south) {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
\end{pgfonlayer}
% Put an image in the main layer
\node at (current page text area.center) {\includegraphics{example-image-a4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]